# wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) ruby warrior intermediate error that doesn't make any sense

Tags: ruby, arguments

I'm doing level 2 of ruby warrior on intermediate and every time I run this I get this error even though it doesn't seem I should. I am very new to ruby so I'd appreciate it if someone could tell me why this is happening even though I'm passing warrior for glance and glance has 1 slot for a variable to

here's the error:

```
 wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
    Player.rb:24:in `glance'
    Player.rb:6:in `play_turn'
```

here's my code:

```
class Player

  def play_turn(warrior)
    @warrior = warrior
    glance(warrior)
    actions
  end

  def actions
    @warrior = warrior
    glance(warrior)
    if rightempty
      warrior.walk!(:right)
    elsif forwardenemy && rightempty == false
      warrior.fight!
    else
      warrior.walk!(warrior.direction_of_stairs)
    end
  end

  def glance(warrior)
    @wariror = warrior 
    forwardempty = warrior.feel.empty?(:forward) 
    leftempty = warrior.feel.empty?(:left) 
    rightempty = warrior.feel.empty?(:right) 
    backwardempty = warrior.feel.empty?(:backward)
    forwardenemy = warrior.feel.enemy?(:forward) 
    leftenemy = warrior.feel.enemy?(:left) 
    rightenemy = warrior.feel.enemy?(:right)
    backwardenemy = warrior.feel.enemy?(:backward)
    forwardcaptive = warrior.feel.captive?(:forward)
    leftcaptive = warrior.feel.captive?(:left)
    rightcaptive = warrior.feel.captive?(:right)
    backwardenemy = warrior.feel.captive?(:backward)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not with the number of arguments being passed to `glance`, it's what's happening within that method.

You're calling `empty?` with one argument e.g. `:forward` when it doesn't take any - hence the error "1 for 0"